# Scala - the return using a for() or foreach() in a list

Tags: scala, loops

How I can build `a string` (not to print it) from the returned value of a `foreach` or `for` statement applied in a `List`? 
Let say, I have this:

```
val names = List("Bob", "Fred", "Joe", "Julia", "Kim")
val x: String = for (name <- names) name //I don't need this println(name)
```

These `name` returned string I am trying to put in a `String`, connecting them by a `space`.?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`mkString(sep: String)`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterable@mkString(sep:String):String) function:

```
val names = List("Bob", "Fred", "Joe", "Julia", "Kim")
val x = names.mkString(" ")      // "Bob Fred Joe Julia Kim"
```

Comment: No shame not knowing it existed! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

`for` and `foreach` return `Unit`. They are only for side effects like printing. `mkString` is your best bet here, as Jean said. There's a second version that lets you pass in opening and closing strings, e.g.,

`scala> names.mkString("[", ", ", "]")
res0: String = [Bob, Fred, Joe, Julia, Kim]`

If you need more flexibility, `reduceLeft` might be what you want. Here's what `mkString` is doing, more or less:

`"[" + names.reduceLeft((str, name) => str + ", " + name) + "]"`

One difference, though. `reduceLeft` throws an exception for an empty container, while `mkString` just returns "". `foldLeft` works for empty collections, but getting the delimiters right is tricky.

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation. I was working with numbers and collections that hold numbers and "opss" I facet a situation that I had to work with string, thus I was trying to use foreach - I failed :( Thanks again.